# How to publish a sitemap.xml to my website?

Tags: go, sitemap, beego, xml-sitemap

I did not have programming background and I learned to code completely by Google search so please excuse me if the question is not totally clear. I tried to search a this issue but could not find an answer.

I have built a website with React + Golang (Beego framework). Now I am trying to add a sitemap.xml to my website so that when people go to `mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml`, they will see the sitemap. I already generated the xml file but I am not sure where to put it.

I tried to set a URL in Golang as `/sitemap.xml` but Golang (Beego) does not render xml file and shows an error. I can put that file into folder `static` and access that file at `mywebsite.com/static/sitemap.xml` but I want it to be `mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml`.

I think I am trying to do it the wrong way. Really appreciate any advice.

Comment: in gin you can use ```router.StaticFile```, but in gee have not it, you can use rederict ```mywebsite.com/sitemap``` rederict to ```mywebsite.com/static/sitemap.xml```

Comment: If you are serving it on route `/sitemap.xml` and doesn't show properly then  first pass the right Content-Type header `Content-Type: application/xml` and make a basic handler to serve it on that route, I asume you wrote the handler for that path that reads the xml file and writes it as response with the headers set?